# Show a subview in Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette.js

I use Marionette for my JavaScript application (requirejs for module structure). Application has router and controller. When starting, application renders the root view. Controller executes actions on each route and shows a subview.

To show a subview, I transmit a root view in a controller with options. It is a first way I see.

Application code

```
define([

    'marionette', 
    'router', 
    'controller', 
    'view.application',

], function (

    Marionette, 
    Router, 
    Controller,
    ViewApplication
) {

    return Marionette.Application.extend({

        onStart: function () {
            this.view = {};
            this.view.application = new ViewApplication();
            this.view.application.render();

            new Router({
                controller: new Controller({
                    view: this.view.application,
                }),
            });

            if (Backbone.history) {
                Backbone.history.start({
                    root:       '/',
                    pushState:  true,
                });
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Controller code

```
define([

    'marionette',
    'controller.category',

], function (

    Marionette,
    ControllerCategory
) {

    return Marionette.Object.extend({

        initialize: function (options) {

            this.view = {};
            this.view.application = options.view;
        },
        category: function () {

            new ControllerCategory({
                view: this.view.application,
            });
        },
    });
});
```

Controller Category code

```
define([

    'marionette',
    'view.category',

], function (

    Marionette,
    ViewCategory
) {

    return Marionette.Object.extend({

        initialize: function (options) {

            this.view = {};
            this.view.application = options.view;

            this.view.category = new ViewCategory();
            this.view.application.showChildView('main', this.view.category);
        },
    });
});
```

Another way I see, is to create a global object, store a root view in it and then use it further (e.g. `App = { Views: { Root: this.view.application, }}`).

Am I right? Is it the best ways to show a subview depending on route? Or does some better way exist?